# Maximum-Minimum value of sum of modulus of complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, maxima-minima

> *Prove that*
>
> $\sqrt{7\over2} \leq |1+z| +|1-z+z^2| \leq 3\sqrt{7\over6} $
>
> for all complex numbers with $|z| = 1$

**My approach**

Let t = $ |1+z|$

$t^2 = |1+z|^2 = (1+z)\cdot(1+\bar{z})$

= $1+\bar{z}+z+z\cdot\bar{z}$

= $1+ 2Re(z)+|z|^2$       = 2+2Re($z$) = $t^2$

$\Rightarrow Re(z) =$ ${t^2 - 2}\over 2$

> *Now for $|1-z+z^2|$*
>
> Let s = $|1-z+z^2|$
>
> $\Rightarrow s^2 = {|1-z+z^2|}^2 = (1-z+z^2)\cdot(1-\bar{z}+\bar{z^2})$
>
> $= 1-\bar{z}+\bar{z}^2-z+z\cdot\bar{z}-z\cdot\bar{z}^2+z^2-\bar{z}\cdot z^2+(z\cdot\bar{z})^2$
>
> $= 1-(\bar{z}+z)+(\bar{z}^2+z^2)+ |z|^2-z\cdot\bar{z}\cdot(z+\bar{z})+|z|^2$
>
> $= 1-2Re(z)+\bigl((z+\bar{z})^2-2z\cdot \bar{z}\bigr)+1-2Re(z)+1$
>
> $= 1-2Re(z)+\bigl((2Re(z))^2-2\cdot 1\bigr)+1-2Re(z)+1$
>
> $=3-4Re(z)+4\cdot \bigl(Re(z)\bigr)^2 -2$
>
> $=1-4Re(z)+4\cdot \bigl(Re(z)\bigr)^2 $
>
> $\Rightarrow s^2 = \biggl(2\cdot Re(z)-1\biggr)^2$
>
> $\Rightarrow s = |2Re(z)-1|$
>
> $s= |t^2-3|$
>
> $\Rightarrow |1-z+z^2| = |t^2-3| $

**But the correct solution says that $|1-z+z^2| = \sqrt{|7-2t^2|}$**

**Where did I go wrong ?**

**Also I want to solve this question using properties of complex number and then find maximum and minimum value of the sum as the function of $z$ and not using ($z = x+y\cdot i$)**

*Any help or worked out solution would be appreciated*

Comment: The given answer seems to be incorrect. When I put $z=-1$, I get $t=|z+1=|0$, $|z^2-z+1|=3$ and $\sqrt {|7-2t^2|}=\sqrt 7$ which is not the same as $|z^2-z+1|$.

Comment: On the other hand, if we plug $t=0$ into $|t^2-3|$, we get $3$. This is exactly the value of $s$.

Comment: Are you sure that the question is correct? When I put $z=\frac {1}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ into $|1+z|+|1-z+z^2|$, I get $\sqrt 3$. This is less than $\sqrt {\frac{7}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given inequality bounds in the question were **wrong**

The correct bounds will be $\sqrt{3}$ and $13\over{4}$

Let me continue my solution

Let t = $ |1+z|$

$t^2 = |1+z|^2 = (1+z)\cdot(1+\bar{z})$

= $1+\bar{z}+z+z\cdot\bar{z}$

= $1+ 2Re(z)+|z|^2$       = 2+2Re($z$) = $t^2$

$\Rightarrow Re(z) =$ ${t^2 - 2}\over 2$

> *Now for $|1-z+z^2|$*
>
> Let s = $|1-z+z^2|$
>
> $\Rightarrow s^2 = {|1-z+z^2|}^2 = (1-z+z^2)\cdot(1-\bar{z}+\bar{z^2})$
>
> $= 1-\bar{z}+\bar{z}^2-z+z\cdot\bar{z}-z\cdot\bar{z}^2+z^2-\bar{z}\cdot z^2+(z\cdot\bar{z})^2$
>
> $= 1-(\bar{z}+z)+(\bar{z}^2+z^2)+ |z|^2-z\cdot\bar{z}\cdot(z+\bar{z})+|z|^2$
>
> $= 1-2Re(z)+\bigl((z+\bar{z})^2-2z\cdot \bar{z}\bigr)+1-2Re(z)+1$
>
> $= 1-2Re(z)+\bigl((2Re(z))^2-2\cdot 1\bigr)+1-2Re(z)+1$
>
> $=3-4Re(z)+4\cdot \bigl(Re(z)\bigr)^2 -2$
>
> $=1-4Re(z)+4\cdot \bigl(Re(z)\bigr)^2 $
>
> $\Rightarrow s^2 = \biggl(2\cdot Re(z)-1\biggr)^2$
>
> $\Rightarrow s = |2Re(z)-1|$
>
> $s= |t^2-3|$
>
> $\Rightarrow |1-z+z^2| = |t^2-3| $

**Now we have** $|1+z| = t$ and $|1-z+z^2| = |t^2-3|$

So the thing $|1+z| $ + $|1-z+z^2|$ becomes t + $|t^2-3|$, **let's call it f(t)**

**Case 1 :** if $t^2>3$

f(t) = $t+t^2-3$

To fetch maximum or minimum value,
we differentiate with respect to t and equate the slope with 0 or use the formula of vertex of a parabola.

**Using calculus**

${d\over{dt}}(t+t^2-3)=0$

$\Rightarrow 1+2t =0$

$\Rightarrow t = {-1\over 2}$

$t^2 = {1\over 4}$ which is $< 3$

This means $t^2$ can never be greater than 3

**Case 2 :** $t^2\leq 3$

f(t) becomes $t + -t^2+3$

${d\over{dt}}(t-t^2+3)=0$

$\Rightarrow 1-2t =0$

$\Rightarrow t = {1\over 2}$

Clearly this is point of maxima as the parabola was inverted ($\because$ coefficient of $t^2$ was $< 0$)

So the maximum value of $t + -t^2+3$ = ${1\over 2} - {1\over 4} +3$ = ${13\over 4}$

**For minimum value**

*the minimum value of the downward parabola is always $-\infty$*

But we have modulus in the term $|t^2-3|$ which changes the sign when $t^2<3$

So, the minimum value of the expression $t +|t^2-3|$ is attained when :

$t +t^2-3 = t -t^2+3$

This gives $2t^2 = 6$ $\Rightarrow$ $t^2 =3$

$\Rightarrow$ $t = \pm \sqrt 3$

But t was |1+z| so it can't be negative, leaving us with $t = \sqrt 3$

So minimum value of the expression $t +|t^2-3| =  \sqrt 3 + |3-3| =  \sqrt 3$

Hence the inequality is

> $\sqrt 3 <  |1+z| + |1-z+z^2|< {13\over 4}$

The question is from the book "Complex Numbers from A to Z" by Titu Andreescu and Dorin Andrica
Problem number 5 from 1.1 page number 13

Answer (score 1):

Let $$F(u)=|1+z|+|1-z+z^2|, z=e^{iu}, u\in \Re$$
$$F(u)=2|\cos(u/2)|+\sqrt{[1-\cos u+ \cos (2u)]^2+[\sin u -\sin (2u)]^2}$$
$$\implies F(u)=2|\cos(u/2)|+\sqrt{(2 \cos u-1)^2}=2|\cos(u/2)|+|2\cos u-1|.$$
$F(u)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ and it is symmetric w.r.r. t. $\pi$.
So studying it for max/min for $u\in [0,\pi]$ would suffice.

When $\cos u \ge 1/2 \implies u\in[0,\pi/3]$, we can write
$$F(u)=2 \cos(u/2)+2\cos u-1 \implies F'(u)= -\sin(u/2)-2 \sin (u) \implies F''(u)=\frac{1}{2}\cos (u/2)-2 \cos u$$
$$f'(u)=0 \implies u=0, f''(0)=-3/2, ~\text{so a max at}~ x=0 \implies F_{max1}=3$$
At $x=\pi/3$, $F(x)$ is continuous but not differentiable, we have $F(\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}$, this value will compete for the global min.

For $u \in (\pi/3,\pi]$,we have $F(u)=2\cos(u/2)+1-2\cos u \implies F'(x)= - \sin(u/2) + 2\sin u=0 \implies -\sin(u/2)[4\cos(u/2)-1]= 0 \implies u_0 = 2\cos^{-1}(1/4), F''(u_0)<0, ~\text{so next local max at}~ u=u_0\implies F_{max2}=f(u_0)=13/4$

Finally, $\sqrt{3}\le F(u)\le 13/4$, in the Fig. $F(u)$ below the red line marks $13/4$ (global max) and blue line marks $\sqrt{3}$ (global min).

[image]

Comment: My approach leads me to the same solution √3 ≤ |1+z| + |1-z+z²| ≤ 13/4. But the question has different bounds. That's why I'm confused. Does the question have wrong inequality bounds?

Comment: Since the function is plotted here, now there is no doubt. You may choose this answer. You may add  a comment in your question in an Edit. Or you are also entitled to post your proof if it looks different. Let me congratulate you for reach the correct answer. What is the source of this problem !?

Comment: I do agree that a truly complex variable solution  remains elusive, but no one should accept a wrong end result!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have posted my solution that lead me to the same solution as yours,  you can see it now. Also sorry for the delay (I was having exams)