# Proving that $\sqrt{3} \le 2\cos(x/2)-2\cos x +1\le 13/4, x \in [\pi/3,\pi]$

Tags: calculus, roots

Recently, in order to answer a proposed complex variable question in an MSE post with a wrong answer, the following inequality $$\sqrt{3} \le 2\cos(x/2)-2\cos x +1\le 13/4, x \in [\pi/3,\pi]~~~~(*)$$
was proved by me. However, the response has been neutral. In a hope to revive interest in this problem, here the question is: How to prove (*) using different methods? The original problem may be referred subsequently.

**EDIT:** The said MSE post:

[Maximum-Minimum value of sum of modulus of complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495943/maximum-minimum-value-of-sum-of-modulus-of-complex-numbers/4496160?noredirect=1#comment9434236_4496160)

Comment: “ _The original problem may be referred subsequently._” Please link the original problem.

Comment: With $x = 2 \pi$ the minimum is clearly $-3$.

Comment: Oh! I am extremely sorry I  forgot to mention $x\in [\pi/3,\pi]$, now I have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = \cos \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)$. Then:
$$\cos(x) = 2u^2-1$$
We know that $\cos(x) = 2\cos^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}x \right)-1$ so it follows that:
$$2u-2(2u^2-1)+1 = -4u^2+2u+3$$
Observe that:
$$-4u^2+2u = -4\left(u^2-\frac{1}{2}u\right) = -4\left(\left(u-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2-\frac{1}{16}\right) = -4 \left(u-\frac{1}{4} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{4}$$

So, it follows that:
$$-4u^2+2u+3 = -4 \left(u-\frac{1}{4} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{4} +3 \leq \frac{13}{4}$$
That proves the right inequality. Now, we know that $u \in [-1,1]$. To find the minimum of the quadratic expression above, we simply let $u = -1$ (that is achieved when $x = 2\pi$). Your proposed minimum doesn't actually hold.

**Edit:**

So, the question was edited to include the fact that $x \in \left[\frac{\pi}{3},\pi \right]$. So, it follows that:
$$\frac{\pi}{6} \leq \frac{x}{2} \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$
This implies that the argument of $u$ is in the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane. Since $\cos$ is decreasing in that quadrant, it follows that:
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \geq u \geq 0$$
In other words, the maximum value for $u = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. It follows that:
$$-4u^2+2u+3 = 2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \sqrt{3}$$
and this is the minimum value that our expression can take so we are done.

Comment: Sorry, please see I have edited the question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to account for that change.